# Use aws sdk with Unity on a Mac

Tags: unity-game-engine, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-net

I've installed unity and am using visual studio for editing scripts on a Mac. How would I go about using the aws sdk to access the sqs or other services?

I've looked here: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/blob/master/README.md

But I don't really know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can get started with Unity:
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/blob/master/Unity.README.md

just download the unity package and you should be able to use the aws sdk